# Battery questions

Tags: circuit-design, battery-charging, batteries, battery-chemistry

I have some questions regarding making a battery pack for a electric bike. I’m looking at the Samsung 50E 21700 5000mAh 9.8A Battery as the base.

1. The max discharge current is 9.8A, if I put two of them in parallel, will the max discharge current be 19.6A?
2. How do BMS work to charge the batteries safely?
3. What are some saftey precautions I should take to keep the pack safe?
4. If I have a pack of series of 4 of the batteries to get 14.4V at 5000mah, and I connect a pack of 4 parallel batteries to get 20000mah, can I connect them in series to get 14.4V 20000mah or will that damage the batteries because of the big voltage differences.  And if not, how can I get a desired voltage of 48V and 25Ah? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you find an answer that solved your question, you can accept it by using the tick icon on the left below the dislike arrow

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes
2. They protect against over charge, over discharge, over current and some of them balance the cells which is needed every once in a while.
3. Never charge them unattended, don't charge in cold weather (below 5C), don't charge in hot weather (above 40C), ensure the connections are well secured, ensure the BMS is correctly set for the voltage and current values, never use the pack without the BMS, and always triple check connections while building it.
4. No to get 14.4v at 20AH you need 16 cells, 4 in parallel then in series like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9UTJW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To get a 48V 25Ah battery you need 65 Samsung 50E 21700 5000mAh cells in this configuration:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh6OF1.png)</sup>

Basically you are connecting 5 cells in parallel to form a 3.7V 25Ah battery, then repeating that 13 times and connecting those batteries in series to get the finished battery.

May i ask what is the use case for such a battery? It is a 1.2kWh pack, not a small size.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is want I am trying to make. https://zugobike.com/products/rhino I can’t afford $1800 but I could afford $500 to make my own.

Comment: Also, what makes motors go faster voltage or amperage? Such as instant acceleration not necessarily top speed.

Comment: They kind of go hand in hand, the voltage determins how fast a motor can rotate and how much current it can pull, then current determins the torque produced which determines acceleration

Comment: You can update youe question with your use case and motor type or open a new question if you have more inquiries

Comment: i also updated the answer, should be parallel then series not parallel then parallel

Comment: Acceleration = torque = current; top speed = voltage.

Comment: An important distinction is top speed = max voltage = battery voltage, however current speed = currebt voltage. BLDC motor controllers can vary the effective voltage applied to the motor using PWM to match the current speed.

Answer (score 2):

2. BMS is a balancing that depends greatly on how well matched the batteries are. If they are mismatched there will be problems to overcome due to heat dissipation limits when the weakest cell has reach full charge while the others must be in CV mode where the current is declining. If it is still in CC mode, you have a big heat problem to dump 4.2V*CC amps.

Since the weakest cell charges up the fastest, it also discharges the fastest making it even weaker long term from undercharged condition before the string reaches cut-off.

So there is an exponential runaway on the weakest link in a string especially when aggressive charge and discharge currents and CV and cutoff voltages are used to squeeze the max Wh out of a cell or pack.  This leads to frustrated users with short life cycles.

You have a lot to learn about batteries before you can design them.